# Incredibuild only builds locally

Tags: incredibuild

I am using incredibuild to build C++ projects(Visual Studio 2017). It utilizes 8 cores of my local PC and doesn't distribute work to other remote hosts. I don't have 'Enable standalone mode' checked. Also agent has all the permissions from the coordinator to build on remote host. I initially thought may be firewall is blocking it but my firewall is disabled altogether. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you enable your IncrediBuild license on both initiator and agent?

Answer (score 1):

I am from IncrediBuild support team.

There can be several reasons for the build to run in standalone mode:

1. Your agent is not subscribed or you don't have the C++ package allocated. Please check the Messages tab in the build monitor for License / subscription warnings. If all is good, check the main Coordinator Monitor and see if your Agent status is Enabled and the relevant package is allocated
2. Your build is not big enough so more cores are simply not needed. You can enable the "Avoid task execution on local machine" option in the Agent Settings and see if now it distributes. It is located under Agent Settings -> Initiator -> General.
3. Connectivity problem to other Agents. Check the Messages tab in the build monitor.

If everything looks good but still no distribution, please open a support ticket by right clicking on the IncrediBuild tray icon -> contact support. I will be happy to continue assisting you from there.